# How to find an entity containing a list of id (of the other entity) in a many-to-many relation on MySql/Jpa?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:

- Recipes (id, name)
- Recipes_Ingredients(id, fk_recipe, fk_ingredient, quantity)
- Ingredients (id, name)

I need to find all the recipes that containing a provided list of ingredients.

Es:

I provide a list of ingredients id like 111 (salt), 222(pepper), 333(oil) and I need to find all  the recipes that containing these ingredients. The query should return me all those recipes that contain these ingredients.

I would also need a way to report the query back to Jpa.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT fk_recipe
FROM Recipes_Ingredients
WHERE fk_ingredient IN (111,222,333)
GROUP BY fk_recipe
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fk_ingredient) = 3
```

Join `Recipes` and `Ingredients` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

sql:

```sql
select distinct r.fk_recipe
from Recipes_Ingredients r
where r.fk_ingredient in (111,222,333)
```

In springboot jpa, you can use @Query

```java
    @Query("select distinct r.fk_recipe from Recipes_Ingredients r 
            where r.fk_ingredient in :ingredients")
    List<Long> findRecipe(@Param("ingredients") Set<Long> ingredients);
```

And when you call the findRecipe method, create a Set as the param.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I had already tried this query and it doesn't work. He finds me all those recipes that contain even just one of the listed ingredients. What I need is to find all the recipes that contain at least all the ingredients provided.  For the moment, Akina's solution is currently working